# A manga about a classless swordsman who can copy everyone’s swordsmanship with only seeing one strike

Tags: story-identification, manga

He is kicked out of an arena because they don’t like his style of fighting, and then he meets a princess who fights him and hires him. It is Japanese styled and had 14 chapters? Also, after he wins against the princess, she takes him to the castle and he meets her maid, who then hits a guy with a mop because he was ridiculing the princess and her decisions.

Comment: [The Hero Who Has No Class. (AKA Mushoku no Eiyuu: Betsu ni Skill Nanka Iranakatta n da ga - Sainou Zero no Nariagari)](https://myanimelist.net/manga/121762/Mushoku_no_Eiyuu__Betsu_ni_Skill_Nanka_Iranakatta_n_da_ga_-_Sainou_Zero_no_Nariagari)?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe its *[Tatoeba Ore ga, Champion kara Oujo no Himo ni Job Change Shita to Shite.](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=173704)* (AKA *Story Of A "unemployed" Champion And A Princess Who Together Find Their Happiness*)

> In a world where human "professions" are determined by nature, there was a person who was the strongest, despite being "jobless." Fuuta, who trained harder than anyone else to achieve this and became a champion was cast out and exiled. At the end of his wandering, he was picked up by Lilac M Fangini, the first princess and ruler of a city.

Comment: You could improve this answer by specifying the ways in which this story matches the one described in the question. Adding a synopsis and a link would be helpful as well.

Comment: @LogicDictates - I can't find a single non-infringing link to this manga :-)

Comment: @Valorum - True, I didn't find non-infringing link with that exact title myself. I was able to find a valid link with an alternate title though, and having checked the story out, it includes pretty everything mentioned in the description. The only difference is that it currently only has nine chapters on the sites I've looked at, rather than 14, as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

This might be *[Mushoku no Eiyuu: Betsu ni Skill Nanka Iranakatta n da ga - Sainou Zero no Nariagari](https://myanimelist.net/manga/121762/Mushoku_no_Eiyuu__Betsu_ni_Skill_Nanka_Iranakatta_n_da_ga_-_Sainou_Zero_no_Nariagari)* (The Hero Who Has No Class. I Don't Need Any Skills, It's Okay.).

> "Classes" are given at the age of 10, and the presence or absence of "skills" greatly affect life. Arel, the son of "Sword Princess" Fara and "Magic King" Leon, has been branded as "Classless"... But even without a job or skills, Arel believes he can persevere through effort.

The MC lives in a world where people are assigned classes and related skills by a goddess, when they reach the age of ten. For whatever reason though, the MC is an exception to this rule, and is judged to be classless. So while others are effectively gifted their skills for free, the MC sets about becoming a skilled swordsman through sheer hard work and practice.

Early on in the story, he's challenged to a duel by another swordsman who uses a special "doubled-edged cut" strike, and gives a decent account of himself but loses. Afterwards, he practices by himself in the forest, and is able to replicate this strike. Later, he has a rematch with that swordsman and wins, making use of that strike.

This manga currently has 25 chapters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nope, not it. I