# classless swordsman manga name

Tags: story-identification, manga

He is kicked out of an arena because they don’t like his style of fighting, and then he meets a princess who fights him and hires him. It is Japanese styled and had 14 chapters? Also, after he wins against the princess, she takes him to the castle and he meets her maid, who then hits a guy with a mop because he was ridiculing the princess and her decisions.

Comment: @Valorum - I'm aware of that as a general rule, but in this case, the _exact text_ from [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247050/a-manga-about-a-classless-swordsman-who-can-copy-everyone-s-swordsmanship-with-o) has apparently been copied and pasted into this second question.

Comment: @user142828 - You appear to have posted an exact duplicate of the question you answered; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/250446/20774.